# googleapiclient in python, using updateContact returns 403

Tags: python, google-api

I'm trying to get a list of contacts from google's API, and then update some of them. While running the `updateContact` function I get 403 error `Request person.etag is different than the current person.etag. Clear local cache and get the latest person."` every time.
I'm reading the contact's etag using this code:

```
service = build('people', 'v1', credentials=creds)
results = service.people().connections().list(
        resourceName='people/me',
        pageSize=100,
        personFields='names,emailAddresses').execute()
connections = results.get('connections', [])
```

Then for each `contact` in the `connections`, Im trying yo change the contact givenName and familyName:

```
service.people().updateContact(resourceName="contact's resource name",
                              updatePersonFields="names",
                              body={
                                  "etag": "contact's etag",
                                  "names": [
                                    {
                                      "familyName": "new family name",
                                      "givenName": "new given name"
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              ).execute()
```

The contact's `etag` and `resourceName` are taken from the connection's list response.
for example:

```
print(connections[0])
{'resourceName': 'people/<resource_number>',
 'etag': 'etag string',
 'names': [{'metadata': {'primary': True,
    'source': {'type': 'CONTACT', 'id': 'id number'}},
   'displayName': 'x',
   'familyName': 'x',
   'givenName': 'x',
   'displayNameLastFirst': 'x',
   'unstructuredName': 'x'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Running your exact code **does work**.

I ran  your code and based it on the [Google People Python Quickstart](https://github.com/googleworkspace/python-samples/tree/master/people/quickstart), while changing only two things:

1. The permissions
2. Adding your code

   ```
   SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts']

   ...

   service = build('people', 'v1', credentials=creds)

   results = service.people().connections().list(
       resourceName='people/me',
       pageSize=5,
       personFields='names,emailAddresses').execute()
   connections = results.get('connections', [])

   for contact in connections:
       service.people().updateContact(resourceName=contact['resourceName'],
                                      updatePersonFields="names",
                                      body={
                                          "etag": contact['etag'],
                                          "names": [
                                              {
                                                  "familyName": "new family name",
                                                  "givenName": "new given name"
                                              }
                                          ]
                                      }
                                      ).execute()
   ```